# Difference boolean while moving object?

Tags: animation, modifiers

I'm currently working on a project in which I have a cylinder object, and need to roll it across a box, so that the reverse of the seal is shown.

[image: Here's a picture of my seal resting on the box.]

Basically, I need to roll it over the surface with the difference boolean, but I'm not sure how to do this. My first attempt led me to move and rotate the seal by hand, and resulted in seams from where I either moved it too far, or when the rotation didn't match up with what I had already taken the difference of. Does anyone know if it's possible to animate the seal to roll across the box, using the difference boolean as it goes? Or have any other ideas as to how I could do this?

[image: Here's my first attempt; you can see the seam lines running through the depiction. I'd like it to be smoother without having to do it all by hand.]

Comment: Try to bake a displacement map onto a new simple cylinder and apply it on the flat surface.

Comment: Some solutions may depend on the way your cylinder is done previously. Is it possible to use it (how is it done? Displacement map or other?) or to redo it in another way if a solution can come from that?

Comment: Try using dynamic paint. Here's an example: https://youtu.be/CuPRufEbtZk?t=73

Comment: Have you got around this one yet?  I've knocked up a quickie using plain vanilla mesh keyframes as an alternative to Boolean.  It wouldn't work in the game engine though, only good for video.

Comment: The cylinder was made by scanning a seal in Artec Studio (so I'm dealing with hundreds of thousands of vertices). I need the flat surface to actually have the seal's surface engraved on it, as the object will be turned into an stl, and not rendered.